# Laravel can't play uploaded mp4 video

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel (5.2) application, I've got a simple uploading function that allows the user to upload or record video from webcam, and then play them.

If the user records a video from the webcam, the upload is successful and then he can play it without problems (webm format).

If the user uploads a video in webm format, the upload is successful and he can play it back.

The problem comes when user uploads a `.mp4` video; the upload is successful but the HTML5 player can't play it, and if I reach the video path I've got a 500 error. But from my ftp client I can see the video is there, and if I download it I can play it without problems.

The function that handles video uploading is this:

```
public function uploadvideo() {
    $input = Input::all();
    $destinationPath = 'videos'; // upload path
    $extension = Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting file extension
    $fileName =  uniqid().'.'.$extension; // renameing video
    $upload_success = Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $fileName); // uploading file to given path

    if ($upload_success) {
      Session::put('video', $fileName);
      $mmty =  mime_content_type('videos/'.$fileName);
      return [$fileName,$mmty];
    } else {
        return Response::json('error', 400);
    }
}
```

So after AJAX call to that script it will return video name and mime type, and in the success function just:

```
var video = response[0];
var tipo = response[1];
var string = '<video width="320" height="240" controls><source src="https://myurl/videos/'+video+'" type="'+tipo+'">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>';
$('#webcam').html(string);
```

So, I think problem is not in the uploading stage (file is correctly uploaded), and with webm videos all works just fine, but with `mp4` over can't play them in the HTML5 player I can't even find them using their path in the browser, but I can see them from ftp client, I've got no idea why this is happening, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i figured out what was the problem. mp4 mime type, for some reasons, was not enabled on my server. So i've just enabled it from cpanel (but i think it could be done aswell by .htaccess file).

Comment: How to enable mp4 mime type on localhost server and live server?